# inequality of summation

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, summation

I think about the following inequality:

‎$\sum_{k=1}^n t_k a_k ‎\leq‎ ‎\sum_{k=1}^n s_k a_k$

where $\sum_{k=1}^n t_k‎\leq‎ ‎\sum_{k=1}^n s_k$ and $0<t_k,s_k \leq‎ 1$ and $0<a_k$.
Is the inequality true?
Is there anyone can help me? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the inequality is not true under the current assumptions. If you let $n=2$, $t_1=s_2=a_1=1$ and $t_2=s_1=a_2=.5$, then all $t_k$, $s_k$ and $a_k$ are positive, the $t_k$ and $s_k$ at most one, and the $t_k$ sum to no more than the $s_k$ (here: the same). However, $t_1a_1+t_2a_2=1*1+.5*.5=1.25$ is more than $s_1a_1+s_2a_2=.5*1+1*.5=1$.